# Can I use Get-PnPUserProfileProperty with SharePoint 2013 On Premise?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, pnp

The Get-PnPUserProfileProperty (part of the Officedev Pnp Powershell commandlets) can be used to query User Profiles on SharePoint Online. We must connect to the tenant admin website (https://:-admin.sharepoint.com) with Connect-PnPOnline in order to use this cmdlet with SharePoint Online.

I would like to use the commandlet to talk to an On Premise SharePoint server too

I've tested this, but as far as I can see this commandlet is not included in the On Premise version of the Officedev PNP Powershell Commandlets. In the documentation I cannot find a definite answer.

Can someone confirm that this commandlet does indeed not work with SharePoint Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that commands is only for the SPO not for on-prem. But you can use the below powershell to query the User's profile in on-prem.

The basic PowerShell code for getting a user profile, using the user's login name:

```
[void][reflection.assembly]::Loadwithpartialname("Microsoft.Office.Server");            
$site=new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("https://c05470sp10:7443");            
$serviceContext = Get-SPServiceContext $site;            
$site.Dispose();            
$upm = new-object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($serviceContext);
$userProfile = $upm.GetUserProfile("company\myarlett");
```

this will list all properties

```
$userProfile.Properties | sort DisplayName | FT DisplayName,Name,@{Label="Type";Expression={$_.CoreProperty.Type}}
```

read more options here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20692.sharepoint-2013-get-set-and-copy-user-profile-properties-using-powershell.aspx